# Show a form as a dialog on another form via thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

The following code gives "cross thread operation" exception. Just because of "form2.ResumeLayout(false)". And if this statement is commented, I can't see browser in form. I know the need of ResumeLayout(false) but is there a solution?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1:  Form
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    { if (disposing && (components != null)) { components.Dispose(); } base.Dispose(disposing); }
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;

    public Form1()
    {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(64, 47);
        this.button1.Text = this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Text = this.Name = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 clss = new Class1();
        clss.startme();
    }
}

class Class1
{
    public void startme()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Run));
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start(null);
    }
    private void Run(object j)
    {
        WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://dshift.sharepoint.com");

        Form form2 = new Form();
        form2.SuspendLayout();
        form2.Controls.Add(webBrowser1);
        form2.ResumeLayout(false);
        Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            form2.ShowDialog(Application.OpenForms["Form1"]);
        }));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: try calling your resume layout on Form_Load event of form2.

Comment: All UI should be shown in a single thread, called the UI thread. That's what the "cross-thread exception" is telling you. Why does this form need to run in a separate thread?

Comment: @Sudhakar: i tried adding "form2.Load += new EventHandler(form2_Load);" but i dont know why form2_Load is not fired; though form shows up (without browser).

Comment: @Cody Gray: Actually I have a big application. I created this sample app so i can debug easily and post it on stackoverflow. That application has a thread that needs to show a form when needed (not always). Problem is i want to show it as dialog. because in some scenario, this form might go on back and user never knows he need to input some where.

Comment: Hmm it will fire. where did you place ?

Comment: @Sudhakar:

Form form2 = new Form();
form2.Load += new EventHandler(form2_Load);
form2.SuspendLayout();
form2.Controls.Add(webBrowser1);
Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
    form2.ShowDialog(Application.OpenForms["Form1"]);
}));

Comment: I don't understand what that means. If you show the form as a modal dialog, it *can't* go to the back. That's the whole point of modality. You still haven't provided a reason why this form needs to be on a separate *thread*.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Yes a modal dialog cannot go on back but the code above is not allowing me to show the form as a modal dialog.

Comment: @Tamour Ahmad OK. Have to see. But why do you have to create another thread to show the modal dialog. you can show it the form1 class itslef. and my suspect is set the boundaries for your browser control (x,y,width and height) and also make sure that Visible property=true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WebBrowser.Navigate() call is the problem.  That forces the native window handle for the control to be created and that happens on the worker thread.  Some time later you force the form's native window to be created with the ShowDialog() call.  But that happens on another thread, the main UI thread thanks to the Invoke() call.

Now there's a mismatch, the form's window is owned by the main thread but the browser's window is owned by the worker thread.  Winforms steps in to remind you that this is illegal, the child windows must be owned by the same thread as the container window.  A workaround is to move the Navigate call inside the anonymous method.

You probably arrived at this code because you also got an IllegalOperationException when you tried to display the dialog without the Invoke() call.  Which would be the normal thing to do if you actually want to run the dialog on a worker thread.  Winforms raises the exception because it doesn't like the Owner of a window to be a window on another thread.  Which is actually legal in Windows, Winforms fumbles the check.

You can work around this by pinvoking SetParent().  And byte my tongue, in this very special case and never do this in any other circumstance, by temporarily setting Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to false.  Emphasis on *temporarily*.  Additional work is needed to ensure the form is actually modal to the window on the main thread and that it gets re-enabled *before* the dialog disappears:

```
var owner = Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
form2.Load += delegate {
    // NOTE: just as a workaround for the Owner bug!!
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    form2.Owner = owner;
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;
    owner.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => owner.Enabled = false));

};
form2.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler((s, ea) => {
    if (!ea.Cancel) {
        owner.Invoke(new Action(() => owner.Enabled = true));
        form2.Owner = null;
    }
});
form2.ShowDialog();
```